# SSIS parameterize testing in Dev environment

Tags: sql-server, deployment, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I have created a parameter:

```
Suppression_FileName Z:\1_Offshore\Test1\
```

The ETL design is

```
Table -> Flatfile
```

In the flatfile connection manager I have given as 
expression properties:

```
@[$Package::Suppression_FileName]\ + "File1.txt"
```

The package is working fine and output is getting generated.

I am in Development environment, if tomorrow I need to move to QA, where do i change the path?

Thanks, for reply.

I have project under which 10 packages are there, how to deploy only 1 package in that, there's no option to deploy.

Thanks, Naveen

[image]

Thanks for replies,

I have the below SQL in OLEDB source, the database names HEX_TST and HEX_CST are to be paratemerized.
created the SchemaName and created a variable to make it paramterized.

Selected "SQL command from variable"

"Select A.Empno
from " 
+ @[$Project::SchemaName_TST] + ".HEX_TST.DBO.Emp E 
inner join " 
+ @[$Project::SchemaName_CST] + ".DBO.Dept D 
on E.Deptno = D.Deptno"

I got the below error. Integration service is using paramters, to make it compatible with package deployment model, 
remove the paramters.
Is the correct way to do it, please let me now.

Comment: The answer to this depends entirely on your deployment method and server environment. Please add further details to your question.

Comment: https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2015/1/4/parameterizing-connections-and-values-at-runtime-using-ssis-environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the expression must be edited to:

```
@[$Package::Suppression_FileName] + "\\File1.txt"
```

Now, in order to deploy a single package to sql server, there are many methods to achieve that, you can refer to the following link for more information:

- [Deploy Packages to Integration Services Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/deploy-integration-services-ssis-projects-and-packages?view=sql-server-2017#deploy-packages-to-integration-services-server)